# Django ORM : Select rows from table A if it has the same id(FK) in the table B, where the rows in A are selected if it satisifies a condition:

Tags: python, django

I have table hospitals and other table departments. I need to do a search operation based on the city. When the user selects the city and types the department, it should check for hospitals in the hospital's table working in the user given city and then check in the department's table whether any of those hospitals are there in the table with the user given department.

How do I do this with Django ORM?

```
class HCSProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  fname = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
  lname = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)        
  city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class HCspeciality(models.Model):
  hospital = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
  speciality = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
  hospital_id = models.ForeignKey('HCSProfile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Where do you store department field?

Comment: HCspeciality table, which the hospital adds their departments while signup

Comment: speciality is department am i right?

Comment: Yh, thats right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
# filter departments to only include hospitals available in the selected city
result = HCspeciality.objects.filter(hospital__city=user_city)
# further filter on department name
result = result.filter(speciality=user_speciality)
```

Of course replace `user_hospital` and `user_city` with the variables you collect from the user.

Note the use of double underscore to filter on a foreign key's own field `hospital__city`.